# Resize UILabel in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am using this code to output a tableView with UILabels that replicate the look of columns.

There are currently 2 labels, but I'm adding a third so I need to make them a little less wide so all 3 can fit.

I commented out the 2 lines that add a 3rd "column" that will show username text.

How can I adjust the code so that I can fit 3 columns instead of 2 within in `UITableView`.

[image]

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AuditGridCell %i", indexPath.row];
        GridTableViewCell *cell = (GridTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[GridTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
            [(GridTableViewCell *)cell clearColumns];
        }

        int is_row_bold = 0;
        NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        float sizes[10] = {CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, 250.0, 100.0, 125.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

        if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            [self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            sizes[0] = CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH_PORTRAIT;
            sizes[1] = 200.0;
        }

        float sum_total = 0.0;
        if (1) {
            int spacer_width = 5;
            UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, spacer_width, tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
            sum_total += spacer_width;
        }   

        if (0 == indexPath.row) {
            is_row_bold = 1;
    //        [values addObject:@"Username"];
            [values addObject:@"Description"];
            [values addObject:@"Date"];
        } else {
            int index = indexPath.row - 1;
   //       [values addObject:[[self.auditRecords objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"username"]];
            [values addObject:[[self.auditRecords objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"description"]];
            [values addObject:[[self.auditRecords objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"date"]];
        }

        for (int it=0; it < [values count]; ++it) {
            UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sum_total, 0.0, sizes[it], tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
            sum_total += sizes[it];
            [(GridTableViewCell*)cell addColumn:sizes[it]];
            label.text = [values objectAtIndex:it];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        }
        [values release];

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question precisely?

Comment: How can I adjust the code so that I can fit 3 columns instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your coding style when you are working with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Although your implementation with the `for` loop makes it seem simple and nice, but in fact, just adding values to the `cell.contentView` without iteration is much simpler. I would suggest that you can just create three `UILabel` fields, such as `label1`, `label2`, and `label3`. And you can provide them the text for the each `index path` and finally add them as a subview to the `cell.contentView`.

This is really simple, and you will be able to see 3 labels each row.

Note: With this method, you will need to set the frame size of the 3`UILabels` perfectly so that you do not mess up the way they look.

**A Better Approach:**

The above implementation is the simplest one, but has a problem with `cell reusability` and if you scroll  up and down with that setup, you can see all the `UILabels` overwritten and messing up the entire view. This problem is *bound to happen* ~ unless you have a uitableview that is smaller than the current view and you have an `unscrollable` view.

**Solution:**

Subclass the `UITableViewCell` and create your own `CustomUITableViewCell` with 3 `UILabels` embedded in it and use that for your implementation of the tableView with `reusability`.
You will need to override the `layoutSubviews` method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

// In this example we will never be editing, but this illustrates the appropriate pattern
[self.contentView addSubview:self.label1];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.label2];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.label3];
[super layoutSubviews];

}
```

This implementation is bug-free and it is also quite simple and logically awesome (once you get a hang of it, you will be able to subclass any structure and create your custom view).

Comment: Thanks Legolas.  The way you described is the way I code myself.  But the code in the question is someone else's code that I'm modifying just to add that 3rd column so I don't want to rewrite everything.  All 3 columns are working now, I just need to reduce the horizontal size of them so I can see them all.

Comment: I see. Subclass the `UITableViewCell`, add labels with appropriate font size and frame width, and I think they should look pleasing now. :)

Comment: legolas I'm not so sure about overriding `layoutSubviews`. If I place a log in there it is called every time a cell is put on screen, which does not sound very efficient for something that only needs to occur once throughout the lifetime of the object. Should you not add the subviews in `init`? Of course I could be being dumb and doing something wrong to make `layoutSubviews` be called all the time.

Comment: They should be added in `-init`. You override `-layoutSubviews` when you want to specify new frames for subviews depending on the state of the view (i.e. editing). Any changes in `-layoutSubviews` will automatically be animated.

Comment: @MarkAdams Haha. Thanks for typing this before I showed up :) @Paul.s Details with regards to the init method is kinda obvious. It all depends on what you require for your `uitableView`.

Comment: Isn't there just a line in my code I can edit to just narrow each label?  Thats all I need for now.

Comment: So this line?  `UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sum_total, 0.0, sizes[it], tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];`  I should change from `sizes[it]` to some `int`?

Comment: I tried changing that and it seems to change the label size, but the placement is still the name.  For example, the spacing between the labels does not change, but the label is reszing because text is getting cut off.